# Is my "for it" usage correct?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I have a custom "About Me" and it goes like this

"I drink Red Bulls 'n Coffee everyday
For it helps the troubles go away!

Life becomes just a simple heart and headache
Just by taking couple of cans, in the end

All the pain you take every day
What else can fix it anyway?"

([There was some relatable jingle that I tried to reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZDxv30hiMk))

I was thinking "for it" stands as "because 'it' is something that make something eg my sentence" but in context it can also mean "doing something so 'it' can do something eg The kid was having hard time socializing so I sacrificed some of my time for it to happen"

So in the end, is there anything wrong or incorrect in my status? It is quite understandable but I wonder how correct it is.

Comment: That use of "for it" sounds a bit old-fashioned compared to "because it" (and compared to the rest of your poem), but is correct. The rest though - not so good. No idea what's happening to your rhyme scheme or puctuation.

Comment: I'd agree.  There's nothing wrong with "for it" (if it helps the poetry)  The rest.... less good.

Comment: "I drink Red Bull 'n coffee everyday
As they help **my** troubles go away!

The rest of the poem is still in need of help...

Comment: It might be good to edit out the other two stanzas, because they are unrelated to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of **for** in this way is entirely appropriate, if a little old fashioned sounding.  Particularly in a poem, especially one meant to recall a jingle, it fits nicely.

*For* was the Old English word meaning *because*, and that direct replacement definition of the word still pops up from time to time.  However, a word-to-word replacement is becoming less and less used.  In American English it is rare to hear it outside of literary settings where it is needed to fit tone or meter, or in certain religious settings (ex: a church sermon using the King James Version of the Bible, which was published in 1611, and the fire and brimstone sermon that might accompany it).

> For I am convinced that neither death, nor life [...] will be able to separate us from the love of God..." (Romans 8:38-39)

Your second meaning/usage is much more common in modern speech, however, it is still very close to the first meaning. Instead of a word-for-word replacement, *for* can be replaced with a short phrase containing *because*.  Using your sentence:

> The kid was having hard time socializing, so I sacrificed some of my time **for** it to happen.

> The kid was having hard time socializing, so I sacrificed some of my time **because I wanted** it to happen.